# Android: Custom Viewgroup draws children incorrectly (on old devices)

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-canvas

I have implemented a custom pager that is very similar to ViewPager. It takes use of canvas to make the scrolling effect. It works as intended on new devices (Android 4.2) but it doesn't on older ones (Android 2.3).

onDraw looks like

```
    Log.d(TAG, "onDraw()");
    if (mSwipe != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Swipe effect=" + (mSwipe.lastX - mSwipe.startX));
        canvas.translate(mSwipe.lastX - mSwipe.startX, 0);
    }

    Page current;

    current = getPage(mPosition);
    if (current != null) {
        if (mPosition != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Offset effect=" + current.offset.left);
            canvas.translate(current.offset.left, 0);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Pager width=" + getWidth());

        Log.d(TAG, "Child width=" + current.view.getWidth());
        current.view.draw(canvas);
        // ...
        // Commented out. Used to draw pages around.
        // ...
    }
```

Android 4.2 prints:

```
onDraw()
Pager width=1080
Child width=960
```

Android 2.3 prints:

```
onDraw()
Pager width=480
Child width=420
```

My testing pages are just TextViews with a solid background and some text.

What I get on new device is that background only takes up as much, as the view and drawing nearby views worked just fine.

On older device I get a full screen solid red (the colors of current view) with a text on it. When I draw children, their text is in the right position but their backgrounds actually take up the whole screen and (what it means) overdraws the current page.

Anyone knows why it happens? What can I do about it?

P.S. Child widths are correct. These two devices have very different specifications but child view should be a bit smaller than the parent (my custom) view.

**Screenshots:**
*Ignore application title. It has nothing to do with fragments. This testing project just happened to be in the list of Eclipse projects and I implemented code there.*

Without neighbors:

[image: Android 2.3] [image: Android 4.2]

With neighbors:

[image: Android 2.3 (n)] [image: Android 4.2 (n)]

Answer (score 0):

Check the way you inflate your xml in the custom view - do u provide a parent view to the `inflate` method? If you've set `null` as the parent to this method (the second argument) so the layout params of the parent won't be used to layout your custom view.